# Streaming radio with widest range of genres?

Tags: radio, streaming

(If this is too off-topic for this forum, please suggest another.)

I am a music fan.  All kinds of music, and I mean *everything*.

I hate choosing the music I want to hear, and I hate hearing the same thing over and over or the same style on repeat (like many of the popular streaming services).  I much prefer someone else feed it to me, and I don't want to hear the same song more than 2-3 times per week.  I get horrible, "OCD" earworms when I hear something too often.

I used to be a huge fan of erika.net, but they've been offline for about 18 months now.  If you weren't familiar with erika.net, they might put together a string of music like:  chinese opera, punk rock, rockabilly, Native American chant, noise "art", classical, blues, electronica, jazz, indie rock, TV show theme song, Afropop, and so on... Repeats were uncommon.

Radio SingSing is the best I've found, and WFMU, WXPN2, and KEXP are decent for the weeks-to-a-month range of listening.  Right now though, all of them are sounding repetitive and I'm hunting for some fresh meat.  Searches for "eclectic" or "alternative" radio offer up lists of mostly college stations.  Those are OK for brief period, but usually have a rather limited scope (lots of indie and grunge).

What recommendations are there for streaming radio stations with the **widest range** of musical selections/genres and limited repeats?

Thanks.

Comment: I listen to [Radio Nova](http://www.novaplanet.com/radionova/player), they have a very wide genre spectrum (reggae, rock, hip-hop, electro, world music, weird stuff...). However, they sometimes have "hits of the moments" that can be played be few times for a few days.

Comment: BTW, I don't think you are off-topic because your recommendation question have narrow boundaries, but I recommend you to read the [tour](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) anyway ;-)